# sequelize Association with same Table

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've two tables with the following structure:

```
Product
Product.id
Product.name
Product.brand_id

Brand
Brand.id
Brand.name
```

What I want to accomplish is, to have an assocation (or whatever) on Product that returns products having the same brand_id.

I mean something like Product.other_brand_products[] returning Product results.

I tried to accomplish that with a VIRTUAL attribute, but because of the getter isn't async and I can't query findAll here with a where condition like where: { brand_id: this.brand_id }.

Is it possible to create such an association with latest sequelize?

Thanks for help / ideas!

Comment: It's mean that you want to return products include brand which brand_id = this. brand_id. Right?

Comment: @ChuongTran yes that's exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: Check my answer. Pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted to do with the following definition of a hasMany relation on my product model:

```
models.product.hasMany(models.product, {
  as: 'brand_products',
  foreignKey: 'brand_id',
  sourceKey: 'brand_id',
  useJunctionTable: false
})
```

On my Product model I now have an array (brand_products[]) that I can access to get products having the same brand.

The solution was using foreignKey and sourceKey attribute as well as useJunctionTable: false because in this case I really don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check associate between Product & Brand. Code define like this

```
Product.associate = function (models) {
// associations can be defined here
  Product.belongsTo(models.Brand, {
      as: 'brand',
      foreignKey: 'brand_id',
      targetKey: 'id'
  });

};
```

2.Query

```
var brand_id = 1;
Product.findAll({
    where: {
        brand_id: brand_id
    },
    include: [{
        model: Brand,
        as: 'brand',
        attributes: ['id', 'name'],
    }]
})
.then(products => {

})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('err', err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate. What I'm talking about is more something like this:

Product.findByPk(1).products_with_same_brand[]

I mean, what you posted is just a simple way to get the products with a specific brand_id, that's not what I really want/need. Maybe my explanation isn't that good enough.

Comment: @cham_eleon It's mean that same_brand is array?